# Is it possible to run a Python program within a Java "GraalVM" program?

Tags: graalvm

From the GraalVM examples, they have code like this to run a single line of Python code:

```
context.eval("python", "\nprint('Hello polyglot world Python!');");
```

Yes that works fine in a Java program.

I can also run a Python program from the command line using the "graalpython" program.

---

My question is how do I run a python program from the Java example I mentioned above?

```
context.eval("python", "\nprint('Hello polyglot world Python!');");
```

I tried using the "file:" argument, but that didn't work or I'm doing something wrong.

For example, this did not work:

```
context.eval("python", "file: /path_to_python/test.py");
```

This line of code gives me:

Original Internal Error: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: not implemented

So, maybe that answers my question, but I have to believe you can run a python script from a GRAAL program like you can a single line of code. Hence, this posting.

--

Is running a python program from within a Java program using graal "eval" supported? If so, I would very much appreciate an example of usage.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

You need to build a `Source` object in order to eval a file:

```
File file = new File("/path_to_python/test.py");
Source source = Source.newBuilder("python", file).build();
context.eval(source);
```

Comment: WOW!!! THANK YOU!!!  EXCELLENT!! I will try this tomorrow and post back. BTW, I did not find this information in any of the examples I spent time reviewing. Is there documentation you found that has tips like this? Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry Gilles, I posted the comment above before realizing you were with Oracle Labs. If there is any documentation you could point me to with tips and information like you posted, I would appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like you pass parameters in the build() method.

Comment: You can have a look at the javadoc, in particular for [Context](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Context.html) and [Source](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Source.html). You might also find interesting information regarding how to embed the GraalVM languages [on the graalvm.org website](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/embed/).

Comment: Updated link is https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/embed-languages/